# Implementation of GUIDE GUI buttons

Tags: matlab

I have a question about the implementation of buttons inside the guide framework. I have 2 buttons created and a drop down menu not seen in the below code (referenced in NumC line). The way the program is meant to run is that they select something from the drop down menu, then the Generate button takes directly from the drop down menu. The third button, Optimize, needs the NumC variable and Cities matrix. Is it possible to reference them directly in the Optimize function, or do I first have to use some output feature in the Generate button to make those 2 usable. NumC is easy enough to recapture using the same line as in Generate, but I need the Cities matrix as it's generated.

```
function Optimize_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Optimize (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% --- Executes on button press in Generate.
function Generate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Generate (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
NumC = get(handles.NumCities, 'Value');
NumC = NumC*10;
Cities = rand(NumC,2);
cla                                         %clears current window
plot(Cities(1:NumC,1),Cities(1:NumC,2),'r')
hold on
plot(Cities(1:NumC,1),Cities(1:NumC,2),'*')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **guidata** command to save data to the **handles** structure and make it available to the other function. Note how in the above code, the comment for handles reads *structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)*. So you can do something like this

```
% --- Executes on button press in Generate.
function Generate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Generate (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% etc. everything that you have above

% now save the data
handles.NumC   = NumC;
handles.Cities = NumC;
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

In the body of your **Optimize_Callback** function, the **NumC** and **Cities** should be directly accessible from **handles** as **handles.NumC** and **handles.Cities** respectively.