# How do I use a variable I get from a GUI function to use on another function?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm making an RGB image filter with a GUI where I change certain parameters through a slider in the GUI. I then want to save the image through a pushbutton in the GUI but I can't. Here's a quick insight:

```
function slider5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    im = imread('C:.........jpg');
    C = im;
end

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    imshow(C);
    imsave
end
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946892/implementation-of-guide-gui-buttons/23947775 for a similar question with answer.  Basically, you use the **handles** structure by saving data to it (create a field, in your case handles.C, and assign some value to it) in one callback, then any other callback will have access to that data through *handles*.  (Saving of data is accomplished using *guidata*.)

Comment: Quite helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best option, but you can use global variables.

1. Declare 'C' as `global C;` in the function you read the file.
2. Write `global C;` in the function you want to use. It will be able to use it.